# Data table in cucumber sending nested Json

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, api-authorization

hopping for your help and assistance I'm trying to send nested JSON through cucumber data table , but it's not being sent as expected, I have tried Scenario Outline too, didn't resolve the issue , pls help me to resolve it Thanks in advance

I have the following scenario;

```
Scenario: provider edits new productWorkingDate
    Given productWorkingDates is edited with following fields
      | id       | productId | fromDate   | toDate     | name   | strictHours | maxUsedTicketsQuantity | errorCode |
      | bpvjPBpJ | WaNX2QOd  | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-01 | Test55 | false       | 0                      | 0         |
    And TimeSlots is edited with following fields
      | dayOfWeek | startTime | endTime  | duration | quantity | usedQuantity | active |
      | Sunday    | 14:00:00  | 15:00:00 | 02:00:00 | 0        | 0            | true   |
      | Monday    | 14:00:00  | 15:00:00 | 02:00:00 | 0        | 0            | true   |
      
    Then verify status code is 200
```

and I have the following step definition

```
 @And("^TimeSlots is edited with following fields$")
    public void timeslotsIsCreatedWithFollowingFields(List<Map<String, String>> expectedTimeSlots) {
        TimeSlots timeSlots = new TimeSlots();



              for(int i = 0; i < expectedTimeSlots.size(); i ++) {
                  timeSlots.setDayOfWeek(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("dayOfWeek"));
                  timeSlots.setStartTime(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("startTime"));
                  timeSlots.setEndTime((expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("endTime")));
                  timeSlots.setDuration(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("duration"));
                  timeSlots.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("quantity")));
                  timeSlots.setUsedQuantity(Integer.parseInt(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("usedQuantity")));
                  timeSlots.setActive(Boolean.parseBoolean(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("active")));

              }
```

Actual output is :

```
{
    "productWorkingDate": {
        "id": "bpvjPBpJ",
        "productId": "WaNX2QOd",
        "fromDate": "2022-07-01",
        "toDate": "2022-12-01",
        "name": "Test55",
        "strictHours": false,
        "timeSlots": [
            {
                "id": "Wlqb8XOb",
                "productWorkingDateId": "bpvjPBpJ",
                "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
                "startTime": "14:00:00",
                "endTime": "15:00:00",
                "duration": "02:00:00",
                "quantity": 0,
                "usedQuantity": 0,
                "active": true,
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        ],
        "deletedAt": null,
        "maxUsedTicketsQuantity": 0,
        "errorCode": 0
    },
    "maxUsedTicketsQuantity": 0,
    "error": null,
    "errorCode": 0
}
```

Expected output is :

```
{
    "productWorkingDate": {
        "id": "bpvjPBpJ",
        "productId": "WaNX2QOd",
        "fromDate": "2022-07-01",
        "toDate": "2022-12-01",
        "name": "Test55",
        "strictHours": false,
        "timeSlots": [
            {
                "id": "4lrn8old",
                "productWorkingDateId": "bpvjPBpJ",
                "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
                "startTime": "14:00:00",
                "endTime": "15:00:00",
                "duration": "02:00:00",
                "quantity": 0,
                "usedQuantity": 0,
                "active": true,
                "deletedAt": null
            },
            {
                "id": "dOnz85OV",
                "productWorkingDateId": "bpvjPBpJ",
                "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
                "startTime": "14:00:00",
                "endTime": "15:00:00",
                "duration": "02:00:00",
                "quantity": 0,
                "usedQuantity": 0,
                "active": true,
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        ],
        "deletedAt": null,
        "maxUsedTicketsQuantity": 0,
        "errorCode": 0
    },
    "maxUsedTicketsQuantity": 0,
    "error": null,
    "errorCode": 0
}
```

**POJO class for TimeSlots**

I use in my POJO classes lombok library;

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data

public class TimeSlots {
    private String id;
    private String productWorkingDateId;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private String duration;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Integer usedQuantity;
    private boolean active;
    private String deletedAt;
    private String dayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Step through your code with debugger, you'll see the problem straight away.

Comment: Are you defining a DTO for TimeSlots  ? Share that as well

Comment: @Wilfred Clement I have POJO classes for TimeSlots , i can share it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have redacted most / some of the information that was needed for me to replicate the error, I just constructed a sample from what you have given and have managed to get the desired output

You are creating an object for TimeSlots outside the for loop however it should be within the loop

**Feature File :**

```
Feature: STACK

Scenario: provider edits new productWorkingDate
Given productWorkingDates is edited with following fields
| id       | productId | fromDate   | toDate     | name   | strictHours | maxUsedTicketsQuantity | errorCode |
| bpvjPBpJ | WaNX2QOd  | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-01 | Test55 | false       |                      0 |         0 |
And TimeSlots is edited with following fields
| dayOfWeek | startTime | endTime  | duration | quantity | usedQuantity | active | productWorkingDateId | id       |
| Sunday    | 14:00:00  | 15:00:00 | 02:00:00 |        0 |            0 | true   | bpvjPBpJ             | 4lrn8old |
| Monday    | 14:00:00  | 15:00:00 | 02:00:00 |        0 |            0 | true   | bpvjPBpJ             | dOnz85OV |
```

**Step Definition :**

```
ProductWorkingDate pw = new ProductWorkingDate();
Example ex = new Example();

@Given("productWorkingDates is edited with following fields")
public void product_working_dates_is_edited_with_following_fields(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) {

    pw.setId("bpvjPBpJ");
    pw.setProductId("WaNX2QOd");
    pw.setFromDate("2022-07-01");
    pw.setToDate("2022-12-01");
    pw.setName("Test55");
    pw.setStrictHours(false);

}

@Given("TimeSlots is edited with following fields")
public void time_slots_is_edited_with_following_fields(List<Map<String, String>> expectedTimeSlots)
        throws JsonProcessingException {

    pw.setMaxUsedTicketsQuantity(0);
    pw.setDeletedAt("Test");
    pw.setErrorCode(0);

    List<TimeSlots> listTimeSlots = new ArrayList<TimeSlots>();

    for (int i = 0; i < expectedTimeSlots.size(); i++) {

        TimeSlots timeSlots = new TimeSlots();

        timeSlots.setId(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("id"));
        timeSlots.setProductWorkingDateId(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("productWorkingDateId"));
        timeSlots.setDayOfWeek(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("dayOfWeek"));
        timeSlots.setStartTime(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("startTime"));
        timeSlots.setEndTime((expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("endTime")));
        timeSlots.setDuration(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("duration"));
        timeSlots.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("quantity")));
        timeSlots.setUsedQuantity(Integer.parseInt(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("usedQuantity")));
        timeSlots.setActive(Boolean.parseBoolean(expectedTimeSlots.get(i).get("active")));

        listTimeSlots.add(timeSlots);

    }

    pw.setTimeSlots(listTimeSlots);
    ex.setProductWorkingDate(pw);
    ex.setMaxUsedTicketsQuantity(0);
    ex.setError("test");
    ex.setErrorCode(0);

    RestAssured.given().body(ex).when().post("http://localhost:8080/stack")...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Wilfred Clement, I'v got your idea , helped me to solve my issue, and another Thanks  to @ lucasnguyen17 , appreciate your kindness

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is here**

`timeSlots` in json is an array, but in method `timeslotsIsCreatedWithFollowingFields` you only created 1 object `TimeSlots timeSlots = new TimeSlots();` then edit data by setter. Debug step by step:

```
TimeSlots timeSlots = new TimeSlots();
--------
i = 0; setA(0) ---> A = 0
--------
i = 1; setA(1) ---> A = 1
--------
end: timeSlots(A=1)
```

---

**Update**:
I don't know cucumber, but in general, you need to create a List to convert to Json array.

You need something like this

```
@Given("TimeSlots is edited with following fields")
public void timeslotsIsCreatedWithFollowingFields(List<Map<String, String>> expectedTimeSlots) {
    List<TimeSlots> listTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map<String, String> expectedTimeSlot : expectedTimeSlots) {
        TimeSlots timeSlots = new TimeSlots();
        timeSlots.setDayOfWeek(expectedTimeSlot.get("dayOfWeek"));
        timeSlots.setStartTime(expectedTimeSlot.get("startTime"));
        timeSlots.setEndTime((expectedTimeSlot.get("endTime")));
        timeSlots.setDuration(expectedTimeSlot.get("duration"));
        timeSlots.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(expectedTimeSlot.get("quantity")));
        timeSlots.setUsedQuantity(Integer.parseInt(expectedTimeSlot.get("usedQuantity")));
        timeSlots.setActive(Boolean.parseBoolean(expectedTimeSlot.get("active")));
        
        listTimeSlots.add(timeSlots);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know cucumber, but I put the code to help you get my idea.

Comment: Thank you very much , i have tried your idea , i did exactly as u have shown , but the output  is the same , though it was supposed to work

Comment: I know my code won't work in context of cucumber, but the idea is rest-assured (actually jackson/gson) will convert List to Json array. So you need provide `List<TimeSlots>` not a single object `TimeSlots`